# How safe are the block variables in solidity / ethereum?

Tags: random, ethereum, solidity

Typically, we understand that relying in `block.timestamp` to generate random, since miners could try evaluating `keccak256(block.timestamp)` (let's say our dumb random function is precisely that one) trying to:

- Find a good hash, according to the difficulty.
- Attempting it in a favorable block.timestamp.

This is: theoretically, the random numbers can be "hacked" by the miners. My question now comes by seeing [this post](https://medium.com/gammastack/random-number-generation-on-blockchain-d3141e1efc2) which uses... a similar approach, which a priori I would deem unsafe for similar reasons. But anyway I would like to ask these questions:

1. Are all these variables prone to be manipulated by the miner?
2. When are those values actually decided? (in particular for the meaning of `block.number`, `blockhash(n in 1..256)`, `block.timestamp`.
3. To what extent all the variables used together can be manipulated by a cheating miner?

Answer (score 1):

All on chain "randomness" should be considered deterministic and not truly random. Your level of comfort with different degrees of pseudo random numbers might be determined by the values you are working with or otherwise.

Random Number oracles via VRF or implementations of VDF provide provably random numbers.